# Is there a way to get unclean contents from a google closure Field?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I have a text editor that provides both a source code and Rich Text editor.  Let's say I have the following in my text area

```
<p>A Paragraph</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('.a-class');
</script>
```

I am successfully able to store this text in the RTE, though if I try to take that data out of it (by calling Field.getCleanContents() ) it results in the following

```
<p>A Paragraph</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.a-class');
</script>
```

So, I'm wondering if there is an easy way to prevent closure from stripping out this extra '$' character.

**Update**

After digging through a bunch of code I found out that there was a string.replace happening, and there's [something a little sneaky in the Javascript string.replace function when using double dollar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

```
"foo bar baz".replace("bar", "$$fancy")
> "foo $fancy baz"
```

The way I got around this was by effectively cutting up the string and returning a new string from that.

```
function glue(msg, old, replacement){
  var oldIndex = msg.indexOf(old);
  var prefix = msg.substr(0, oldIndex);
  var suffix = msg.substr(oldIndex + old.length);
  return prefix + replacement + suffix;
}

glue("foo bar baz", "bar", "$$fancy");
> "foo $$fancy baz"
```